# flash[:notice] not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following snippet of code in my controller

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.message = h(@message.message)
    if @message.save
       flash[:message] = "Message Sent. Thank You for Contacting Me"
    else
       flash[:message] = "OOps Something went wrong"
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'contact'
  end
```

When I try to display the flash message in the contact form it doesnot display. I looked up possible solutions, but they dont seem to work. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: This is probably just a typo, but it doesn't hurt to check the obvious first:
In the title you say flash[:notice] and in your method you are setting flash[:message]. Are you by any chance expecting flash[:notice] in your views?

Comment: what code are you using in your view to display the message?

Comment: sorry my bad. It is flash[:message] in the view as well.

Comment: <h1><%= flash[:message] %></h1>

Comment: Could you add the code for the contact action to the question? Also the relevant views.

Answer (score 16):

Your controller is redirecting to :action => 'contact'. Ensure that the template being rendered for that action has the flash notice output.

```
<%= flash[:message] %>
```

Also, you may want to use render :action ... vs redirect_to :action .... Save yourself a request.

Comment: yeah the issue is if I use flash.now[:message] = "Blah Blah" then it works with a render action. But just out of curiosity I was wondering why it doesnt work with the redirect action. And yeah the solution you mentioned is there in contact.html.erb.

Comment: Well flash.now only works for the current state of the action, once you move from it gets cleared. So flash[..] would be what you want to use if you need it in on another request. Since your redirecting, and flash[..] does not work. I wonder if you might have some session problems with your app.

Comment: thats interesting, could be a sessions problem. Let me look into that.

Comment: I guess it was a sessions problem after all.

Answer (score 5):

The flash hash can contain any set of messages you want to save until the next render. Scaffolds usually use the contents of flash[:notice] for notification messages. If you didn't use a scaffold to generate your web page you will have to add `<%= flash[:notice]%>` to your views.

You're setting flash[:message] in your controller. So it's not going to show up anywhere in your view unless your view contains `<%= flash[:message]%>` somewhere.

Your possible solutions are change all occurrences of `flash[:message]` to `flash[:notice]` in your controller or add `<%= flash[:message]%>` to any views that this action could render.

Comment: I had put that in my view, it did not work, Also the next possibility I changed flash[:message] to flash[:notice] and put <pre><%= flash[:message]%></pre> in the view, but that dint work too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I thought a flash message persists even after a redirect. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It might be getting cleared because of the redirect. Does show redirect anywhere?

Comment: whatever key you use in the controller has to match what appears in the view. Also which views did you add the `<%=flash[:message]%>` to?

Comment: let me explain I have a view contact which displays a contact form, the action goes to the same controller but create method, the code for create is above. No other redirects, except the one in create.

Answer (score 3):

Not saying that you wouldn't have tried it, but if I were you I would do something down the lines like

```
<% if flash[:messsage].blank? %>
  <h1> flash hash is blank </h1>
<% end %>
```

If you see the "flash hash is blank" in your browser you know what it means.

**EDIT**:-

Something from the docs "Just remember: They‘ll be gone by the time the next action has been performed." Try this in your controller

```
flash.keep(:message) #keep the flash entry available for the next action
```

Comment: yup tried that, but what I dont understand is why it is being cleared?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a scenario where flash messages will not be preserved. This scenario is when submitting a form which does not contain the CSRF token field. Rails will not be able to verify the CSRF token, so it will not preserve the flash messages. If you are using a plain HTML form, use the `form_tag` helper to automatically add this field for you.

```
<%= form_tag '/example/url' do %>
  <input name="example">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit the Form">
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I wish I could upvote it more than once because I just lost an hour on this exact problem.