# Rails: CanCanCan - AccessDenied error not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, cancan, cancancan

I'm using CanCanCan in my rails app for authorization. The routes and redirects work fine but I don't manage to display the AccessDenied error message (it worked before but I must have messed something up on the way and now it just won't show).

Here's my code:

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, error: exception.message
  end
  ...
end
```

(I changed the default `:alert` to `:error` as otherwise I was ending up with an alert from devise ('You are already logged in').

**views/index.html.haml** (root)

```
= flash[:error] if flash[:error]
...
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work again? Thanks in advance.

**---EDIT---**

Some more fixes I tried (without success):

- Replacing `error` with `message` and `notice`
- Removing the `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied` method completely - it brought me to the standard CanCan error page (so I know the method itself is working).
- Replacing the `exception.message` with a regular string.
- Adding a puts statement before redirection - it gets printed in the console as one would expect.
- As @Anand Shah suggest in an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779405/flashnotice-not-working-in-rails?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), I added the following in my view:

> - if flash[:error].blank?
>     %p flash hash is blank

The hash was indeed empty, so it seems like the flash is not being saved at all. Then I added

> flash.keep(:error)

in my controller but that didn't change anything.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? You don't get redirected or the flash is not showing the message?

Comment: @LuizE. "The routes and redirects work fine but I don't manage to display the AccessDenied error message"

Comment: try `redirect_to root_url, flash: { error: exception.message }`

Comment: @LuizE. this didn't change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue turned out to be my `routes.rb`. In addition to defining the root for devise scope:

```
devise_scope :user do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end

authenticated :user do
  root 'application#show', as: :authenticated_root
end
```

I also had an extra root defined (which basically caused double redirection and therefore loss of the alert):

```
root to: 'application#show'
```

The code from the documentation works just fine after the necessary modification (note I could bring it back from `error` to `alert` without breaking things):

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to root_url, alert: exception.message
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it through a private browser in case the cookies have messed up?

Can you try this format?

```
redirect_to(root_url, {:flash => { :error => exception.message }})
```

Comment: I tried in a private browser and with the format you suggest, no change.

Comment: I think it doesn't save the flash because you redirect.
Can you try just flash.keep in the controller of root_url (where your home controller is)

Comment: I tried - no change. I also wanted to point out that `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end` is the exact syntax from the CanCanCan documentation and it also worked for me previously (with redirection), so I'm afraid the issue lies elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not handling this inline but rather something like:

```
 rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] =  exception.message
    redirect_to root_url
 end
```

The reason it was working before is Rails understands `:alert` and `:notice` as flash messages during the `redirect_to` otherwise you should use the "general purpose `flash` bucket" as they call it via `flash: {error: 'your message'}`

However the `Hash` passed to `redirect_to` can also contain the http status code (`:status`) and url query parameters (anything that is not `:alert`, `:notice`, `:status`, or `:flash` and it all just seems like too much noise (IMO) to put a flash message in there to save 1 line of explicit code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried the format you suggest without any change. I also tried altering `error` to `notice` but also without any luck.